# Change background color in a select option dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, django, forms

I'm rendering a form using django. One of the fields in the form is a select with options.

Rendering form field:

```
{{ form.work }}
```

The select options after rendering are:

```
<select name="work" class="form-control" required="" id="id_work">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
  <option value="chair">The chair</option>
  <option value="table">The table</option>
</select>
```

How can i change the background color for each of the values?
So when i press the dropdown arrow to see all values with different colors.

I used css with no success.

```
select option[value="chair"] {
  background-color: red !important;
}

select option:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

As a note, the form consists of different fields with select options. I use bootstrap 4.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the second style you need to use `nth-of-type`. But as CSS only it works:

```css
select option[value="chair"] {
  background-color: red;
}

select option:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<select name="work" class="form-control" required="" id="id_work">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
  <option value="chair">The chair</option>
  <option value="table">The table</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set some flag as well if there are only 2 drop-down values.

Comment: This is identical to the answer submitted before you. Please don’t duplicate answers.